# Create new row for each not empty column

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm trying to convert an Excel macro to Google Apps Script. I would like to create a new row on a specific sheet for each not empty column in Google Spreadsheets.

My `Inputsheet` looks like the following:

```
ID | Inrellevant Column | Givenmoney | Takenmoney | Othermoney
1  | Data1              | 100        | 200        | 300
2  | Data2              |  400       |            | 500
```

I want to create a new row in another sheet for each not empty cell, so the desired `Outputsheet` would be:

```
ID | Inrellevant Column | Moneycode   | Amount
1  | Data1              | Givenmoney  | 100
1  | Data1              | Takenmoney  | 200
1  | Data1              | Othermoney  | 300
2  | Data2              | Givenmoney  | 400 
2  | Data2              | Othermoney  | 500
```

I tried the following:

```
Outputsheet.getRange('A2').offset(0, 0, Inputsheet.length).setValues(Inputsheet);
```

However I can't see to create a loop to create new rows for each not empty column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hoi Fred, assuming you want the output to appear from the top left cell onwards in the sheet 'Outputsheet', try this code:

```
function myFunction() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive(),
    source = ss.getSheetByName('Inputsheet'),
    target = ss.getSheetByName('Outputsheet'),
    arr = [
        ["ID", "Header 2nd col", "Moneycode", "Amount"]
    ],
    data = source.getDataRange().getValues(),
    headers = data[0];
data.splice(1)
    .forEach(function (r) {
        r.forEach(function (c, i) {
            if (!isNaN(parseFloat(c)) && isFinite(c) && i > 1) {
                arr.push([r[0], r[1], headers[i], c])
            }
        })
    })
target.getRange(1, 1, arr.length, arr[0].length).setValues(arr);
```

}

See this [example sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1l6CQo1xsCyqAUB-8XBGtPa0zQSjFOLTYkx3KptnhCPs/edit?usp=sharing) where you can run the above script from the menu 'My Menu'....

Comment: Thank you, this seems to work when there are only 3 columns on the `Inputsheet` could you tell me how I can select the columns from the `Inputsheet` when there are different values as well in the `Inputsheet` - I've updated my main post.

Comment: Bold doesn't seem to work ? Oh well? Check arr : [] where I added the header of that new column, also check 'i >1' (used to be i > 0) and the addition of r[1] in the push... Hope that helps ?

Comment: PS: I updated the example sheet.. Check if it works as expected.

Comment: Thanks! Works great, for me I kept the header at 0 as you did and changed `i` to a higher value so it would start there.